# Regex for youtube channel URL

Tags: php, regex

how can I validate youtube channel URL using REGEX ?

I found this pattern but it doesn't work properly

```
/((http|https):\/\/|)(www.|)youtube\.com\/(channel\/|user\/|)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}/
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: _"it doesn't work properly"_ - how does it not work properly?

Comment: when I add "s" (without quotes) at the end of users I don't get the error message

Comment: Why didn't you escape the first `.`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is the extra pipe after `user\/`

Here is the corrected regex:

```
((http|https):\/\/|)(www\.|)youtube\.com\/(channel\/|user\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}
```

The reason this is a problem is because it make (channel|user) optional.

A better way to write this regex is

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.com\/(channel|user)\/[\w-]+
```

Comment: Thank You, I removed the pipe from the original code and it worked

/((http|https):\/\/|)(www.|)youtube\.com\/(channel\/|user\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}/

Comment: add _ to the regex for channels exemple : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgrnWaeLQ_zTqaiq858zksA/ 
Note also that Channel id also start by UC

Comment: Channel ids can also contain dashes. Example (fake link, but it is formatted like a real one): https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC57ZBb_D-YRsCxnsdHGSxSQ

Updated regex: `((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.|)youtube\.com\/channel\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,})`

Comment: @ThomasRoss nice, but your update lacks the underscore, which Julien mentioned

Comment: I did a slight edit to suppress captures which aren't that important, and to force uppercase for first character of channel id: `(?:(?:http|https):\/\/|)(?:www\.|)youtube\.com\/(channel|user)\/([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})`

Answer (score 10):

After some in-depth research, I came up with the following RegEx:

```
^https?:\/\/(www\.)?youtube\.com\/(channel\/UC[\w-]{21}[AQgw]|(c\/|user\/)?[\w-]+)$
```

It allows:

- `https` or `http`
- `www.` or not
- `channel/` URLs (since 2015)
- `user/` URLs (legacy)
- custom (`c/`) URLs (since 2016)
- short URLs (`user/` or `c/` removed)

It also validates channel IDs since they follow a pattern:

- Start with `UC`
- 21 characters of `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]` (same as `[\w-]`)
- end with one of `[AQgw]`

Tested with:

```sql
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCARj2eHnsYMuCZDmYZ5q4_g
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUZHFZ9jIKrLroW8LcyJEQQ
https://www.youtube.com/c/YouTubeCreators
https://www.youtube.com/YouTubeCreators
https://www.youtube.com/user/partnersupport
https://www.youtube.com/partnersupport
http://www.youtube.com/partnersupport
https://youtube.com/partnersupport
http://youtube.com/partnersupport
```

Sources:

- https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214
- https://breadnbeyond.com/youtube-marketing/youtube-custom-channel-url/
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101153

Answer (score 5):

To get the channel name or channel id from a youtube URL use:

```
(?:https|http)\:\/\/(?:[\w]+\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:c\/|channel\/|user\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})
```

Works for:

- https://www.youtube.com/user/channelblabla
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/channelblabla
- https://www.youtube.com/c/channelblabla
- https://www.youtube.com/channelblabla

Channel ID's start with 'UC'. I don't know of any other way to recognize channel ID's vs. channel names.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution for me is

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtu((\.be)|(be\..{2,5}))\/((user)|(channel))\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})/
```

This works for

```
http://www.youtube.com/channel/uc_fglsfl
http://youtube.co.uk/channel/asdasgfgjd
https://youtube.com/channel/ghjgk+öää,
https://youtube.net/channel/43568&gsldkfj
https://youtube.de/channel/dtgzu&&dadg 
http://youtube.com/channel/vgujsgh&as=gr
http://youtube.com/channel/xdfhxfgu

let str = 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/uc_fglsfl'
let pattern = '/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtu((\.be)|(be\..{2,5}))\/((user)|(channel))\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})/'
let matchs = str.match(pattern)
//result id
matchs[9]
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me. I just added the validation for /c shortcut that some YouTube channels have.

Updated RegEx:
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtu((\.be)|(be\..{2,5}))\/((user)|(channel|c))\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})

Thank you very much!