# Javascript regex Pattern Match not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I plugged this together from various sources

```
<!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413707/regex-for-youtube-channel-url-->
<body>
  <button onclick="writeytElement()">YTID</button>
  <script>
    function writeytElement() {
      //document.write("<div>Let's print an additional DIV here</div>");
      let str = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/SaphiraLynx';
      let pattern = '/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtu((\.be)|(be\..{2,5}))\/((user)|(channel))\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})/';
      let matchs = str.match(pattern);
      matchs[9];
      document.write("<div>matchs</div>");

    }
  </script>
</body>


<!---pregmatch(UC[-_0-9A-Za-z]{21}[AQgw]);-->
<!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube?rq=1-->
```

However it seems to malfunction.
I.e. /no output/

Is this an issue of mine, or of the code  (see commented section(s) ?
(I might have mangled the variable in the document.write ...

But the script won't work still

Comment: This line is just reading the index from an array but doing nothing with it: `matchs[9];`

Comment: I see, so it cannot be used. Can the "pregmatch(UC[-_0-9A-Za-z]{21}[AQgw]);" be used to retrieve and display the idthen perhaps ? Looks promising

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely with the regex pattern, as it won't match the given string. Try using this regex instead:

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.com\/(channel|user)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})/
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotes from the pattern. Without quotes, it is a regex literal. With quotes, it is simply a string.

```js
let str = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/SaphiraLynx';
// wrong
let pattern1 = '/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtu((\.be)|(be\..{2,5}))\/((user)|(channel))\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})/';
let matchs1 = str.match(pattern1);
console.log(matchs1);
// right
let pattern2 = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtu((\.be)|(be\..{2,5}))\/((user)|(channel))\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,})/;
let matchs2 = str.match(pattern2);
console.log(matchs2);
```

Also, if you want to embed variables within a string, consider using template literals:

```js
document.write(`<div>${matchs}</div>`);
```